# How to add an ID to pyspark dataframe rows that increases only if a certain condition is met?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe, and I want to add an Id column to it that only increases if a condition is met.
Example:
over a Window on col1, if col2 value changes, the Id needs to be incremented by 1.
Input:

```
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   1|   A|
|   1|   A|
|   1|   B|
|   1|   C|
|   2|   A|
|   2|   B|
|   2|   B|
|   2|   B|
|   2|   C|
|   2|   C|
+----+----+
```

output:

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|  ID|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   A|   1|
|   1|   A|   1|    
|   1|   B|   2|
|   1|   C|   3|
|   2|   A|   1|
|   2|   B|   2|
|   2|   B|   2|
|   2|   B|   2|
|   2|   C|   3|
|   2|   C|   3|
+----+----+----+
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `dense_rank` function (pyspark doc [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank)).
Assuming your dataframe variable is `df` you can do something like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
...
df.withColumn('ID', F.dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy('col1').orderBy('col2')))
```